# How to pass select box value with array and store in Database using php

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I want to store an array of values in a `MySQL` database. Here, the `grade` variable is an array which contains value from the html select element. Its currently not working. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
    $query = "UPDATE course_reg set grade=";
    $values = $_POST['grade'];
    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach ($values as $a){
        $valuesArr[] = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
        //$valuesArr[] = $a;
    }
    $query .= implode(',', $valuesArr);
    $grade_upp = mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
?>
```

Comment: update your code with html code

Comment: Your query does not contain a `WHERE` clause and modifies all the rows in the `course_reg` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `'` around your string :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
$query= "UPDATE course_reg set grade=";
$values = $_POST['grade'];
$valuesArr = array();
foreach ($values as $a){
$valuesArr[] = mysql_real_escape_string($a);
//$valuesArr[] = $a;
}
$query .= "'".implode(',', $valuesArr)."'";
$grade_upp=mysqli_query($con,$query);
}
?>
```

NOTE: Stop using mysqli_query instead use [prepared statement](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp). It's not secure.

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you want to do? What is your table structure? You are updating (=changing) rows in the database. Is this what you want? Mysql update query cannot be used to set multiple values into the same field. From your query this is what it looks like you are doing. And the is no where condition to your update. So you would always update all of the rows.

```
if (isset($_POST["sub"])) {
    $query= "UPDATE course_reg set grade=";
    $values = $_POST['grade'];

    foreach ($values as $a){
    $valuesArr[] = mysql_real_escape_string($a);

    $grade_upp=mysqli_query($con,$query.mysql_real_escape_string($a));
    // if your values are strings, you need to put them into '
    // and you might want to add a WHERE clause to your update
}
```

And by the way, using POST variables directly is considered insecure. Have a look at prepared statements - as stated by @FArzad

Comment: I want to update values in database. I kept <select> option in loop. that's why i need array. Basically i did it for grade submission. I store all grades is array and want to update that . Here grade variable is a array.